# How to call a function with inline string with LLVM

Tags: llvm, code-generation, llvm-clang

I've declared a function `print` which will print only string values:

```
declare i32 @printf (i8*, ...)

; Print
@.str_specifier = internal constant [4 x i8] c"%s\0A\00"
define void @print (i8*) {
  call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str_specifier, i32 0, i32 0), i8* %0)
  ret void
}
```

Currently, I use it like so

```
; Example
@msg = internal constant [13 x i8] c"Hello World!\00"

define i32 @main() {
  call void @print(i8* getelementptr ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @msg, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret i32 0
}
```

Can I call while inlining the string value? Something like:

```
call void @print(i8* "HelloWorld!\00")
```

Comment: No, that string is a GlobalValue (something that occupies memory), and such values really, really, really have to have specified linkage. The linkage is internal in your first case and in your second case there'd be nowhere to specify it.

Comment: @arnt Thank you, feel free to add a more elaborated answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The words seem to fail me today. A comment allowed itself to be written, but that was all. Maybe tomorrow.